# What's the best way to save GPS coordinates to be used later? (not using APIs)

Tags: java, android, navigation, gps

I'm trying to save GPS coordinates to something xml/txt/db, something that will keep them even if the app is shut down, and then use them later. I am only trying to save 1 set of coordinates at a time so it doesn't have to be too complex. just can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you mention XML perhaps investigate saving as KML which is more GPS related.  Another option is a Postgis enabled Postgresql database

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save 1 set of coordinates at a time you can easily use  [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)